# What does it mean in assembly when you have ".word "variable""?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have this snippet of code from my book:[image]

I am wondering what the last part actually does? I have seen in other posts on SO where we have a value after .word, but here there is a letter. What is the difference?

Is L3 a vector in this case?, with 3 elements?

Comment: `f` is the address of the symbol `f`, which presumably is defined by a label in `.bss` for that zero-initialized global var.  It's a literal-pool that main can use to get the addresses of the globals.

Comment: The `.word`s are a collection of 3 different independent helper values that it needs, more than a table, vector, or array, we could can make that the analogy.  The helper values are pointers to those variables.  The ordering has to do with the order that the compiler encounters those variables during translation.  The label `.L3` is used by the compiler to access those helper values.  It really doesn't index the helper pointers -- just accesses each helper value more-or-less directly; the math `.L3+4` is a compile time expression, so is the same kind of code as the `.L3` without +0.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you, I am a beginner so I didnt understand everything you said. But is it so that f g and y are pointers? Why can we use f without declaring it? What does f point to?

Comment: No, those variables themselves are not pointers, but the compiler needs helper values to access them, so makes pointers to them.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you, but I do not understand where the values are actually saved. What is it we actually load into r3?

Comment: Since your post only shows a fragment of the complete executable, the actual declarations & storage for these variables is not shown!  You're looking for labels, something like `f:`, `g:`, `y:`, and they are not shown; it is also possible that these are declared as "common", which is simply not shown.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you. So is it so that f and g and y are declared elsewhere, and when we write L3: .word f, we put the memory adress of where we have f: in where L3 is?

Comment: Yes, `.word f` is a helper pointer that the code can reach easily, and uses then to reach `f` itself. This code doesn't otherwise know where `f` is.

Comment: The assembly code shown is not a complete representation of the shown C code: the C code declares the variables, but the assembly does not.